# Video renders fine until frame 487 but black afterwards

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I imported an `MTS` video file format from my video cam and there is this weird synchronization problem where the video strip is stretched farther than the audio strip and hence slow motion effect.

[image]

So i added a speed control to be in sync with the audio which worked perfectly. When i scrub through the video sequencer everything seems fine but when pressing F12 for any frame after 487 it is blank. So when i render the video it displays from 1-486 and then is black for the rest of the video but the sound is still there. Any idea what is going on?

[image]

Comment: Might be the case that the Speed Modifier is shortening the video. Can you upload a .blend file so we can confirm this? I know the Speed modifier is annoying, you have to be kind of specific about how you add it and edit the clip after it's been added. It kind of completely untethers the actual clip playback from the in-editor length of the strip.

Comment: usually when video and audio length don't match it's because blender's framerate is different from the original video. Could it be that your footage was shot at 60fps and blender set to 30fps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the the Frame Rate of the video matches the Frame Rate of the project, if not there will be mis-matching like in your case.

[image]